# PhpMyAdmin - Corrupted characters while loading CSV

Tags: file, import, phpmyadmin, character

I got corrupted characters when loading a CSV file using phpMyAdmin, although I set the characterset to UTF-8. The characters are fine in notepad++.

It's about this word for example: **Šibensko-Kninska Županija**

Maybe someone knows a solution?

This is my query

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/file.csv' INTO TABLE `divisions` CHARACTER SET utf8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (`name`, `code`)
```

Comment: Try using the Import tab instead of directly executing your SQL.

Comment: Thanks for thr reply. Long time no reaction. Your solution in combination with changing the caracterset of phpMyAdmin to utf16 did work. Thanks!

Comment: I'm delighted that it worked for you, too bad I didn't see it when you first made the post.